# Como criar as tabelas ao iniciar o Sisitema com JSF e JPA?

Tags: mysql, jsf, jpa

Galera, como faço para que quando o sistema inicie as tabelas sejas criadas automaticamente? Do jeito que está meu sistema as tabelas só são criadas quando algum tipo de acesso ao banco é feito. Por exemplo na tela de login basta pressionar o botão logar que as tabelas são criadas. Minha intenção é que sejam criadas ao iniciar o sistema.

Estou usando JPA + JSF + MySql

Comment: Qual Servidor está usando?

Comment: Tá usando Hibernate também?

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso eu criaria uma classe que implementasse [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) que é um Listener que verifica quando o inicio e fim de uma aplicação, ao implementar essa classe dois métodos sobrescritos são criados: `contextInitialized()` e `contextDestroyed()`.

No método `contextInitialized()` você inicia o que você quer junto com o servidor, exemplo:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(pu);
    System.out.println("Contexto Inicializado");
}
```

E no método `contextDestroyed()` você coloca tudo que deseja finalizar junto com o servidor, exemplo:

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
   emf.close();
}
```

Por fim é só registrar o `Listener` no `web.xml`

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.util.suaclasse</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso que uso o `wildfly`, eu fiz o seguinte:

Configurei no arquivo *standalone.xml* as seguintes entradas:

Em `<datasources` eu adicionei:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pokemax" pool-name="pokemax" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>senha</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

Em `<drivers`:

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

E adicione o driver do `mysql` no diretório: */opt/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main*.

Caso as pastas não existam pode criar elas normalmente.

Ainda neste diretório, adicione um arquivo chamado *module.xml* com as seguintes informações:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Pronto, só atente para as suas configurações como banco, user, senha, versão de driver do mysql, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Defina o valor da propriedade "**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto**" como "**update**".

Dessa forma, qualquer alteração nas entidades JPA será refletida no banco de dados quando o servidor iniciar a aplicação.

Segue exemplo utilizando MySQL, hibernate e servidor Wildfly 9

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```